# How do I edit the VRAM in VMWare Workstation 12?

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-98, vram

I have a Windows 98 Virtual Machine that I want to increase the amount of VRAM in it.

The problem is, whenever I edit the .vmx file it never notices the changes and will never let me go above 4MB VRAM. How do I do this?

Comment: are the vmware tools installed? I believe that they include a more functional driver.

Comment: Yeah, VMware tools for Win9x.

Comment: Can you provide what your attempting to use as your setting exactly?  The name of the setting must be exact.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you're trying to ask, but I'm trying to edit the .vmx file to set the amount of vram to 128mb.

Comment: I've tried increasing the resolution. but that only sets vram to 16mb. Not nearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the `svga.vramSize = 134348800` setting documented [here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003), right?

According to some other forums I've seen, you may have to set it to a value that is a multiple of 65536.

So, 128MB would be `svga.vramSize = 134348800`, and 1GB would be `svga.vramSize = 1073741824`.

Comment: That didn't work. VMWare didn't edit the .vmx like it used to so that helps, but my VRAM is still stuck at 4MB.

Comment: I have an idea: Could you tell me what resolution multiplied by 4 will give me 134348800?

Comment: No idea.  You do have 3D acceleration enabled, right?  Have you tried uninstalling the video driver in the VM and reinstalling it?

Comment: Maybe but would be beneficial to post the contents of your vmx file in your question.